# Assigning dom id based on model attributes in Rails nested form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a nested form. 
Right now I want to arrange the layout with some CSS but I am facing trouble allocating dom ids to the form.

This is the subject controller.
I want to allocate lesson_type as seen in line 5 as the dom id.

```
 1 def index
 2   @subjects = Subject.all
 3   @subject = Subject.new

 4   lecture = @subject.lessons.build
 5   lecture.lesson_type = "lecture"
    lecture.lesson_groups.build
    lecture.destroy

    tutorial = @subject.lessons.build
    tutorial.lesson_type = "tutorial"
    tutorial.lesson_groups.build
    tutorial.destroy

    laboratory = @subject.lessons.build
    laboratory.lesson_type = "laboratory"
    laboratory.lesson_groups.build
    laboratory.destroy


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @subjects }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

The following is the form.

```
<%= nested_form_for(@subject, :remote=>true) do |f| %>
  <% if @subject.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subject.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subject from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @subject.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject_code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :subject_code %>
  </div>


  <%= f.fields_for :lessons do |lesson| %>

     <%= lesson.label :lesson_type %><br/>
     <%= lesson.text_field :lesson_type, :readonly=>true%><br/>
     <%= lesson.label :name %><br/>
     <%= lesson.text_field :name %><br/>

  <%= lesson.fields_for :lesson_groups do |lesson_group| %>

       <%= lesson_group.label :group_index %><br/>
       <%= lesson_group.text_field :group_index %>
       <%= lesson_group.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>

  <% end %>
```

This is the div where I want to add an id to.

```
  <%= f.fields_for :lessons do |lesson| %>
     <%= lesson.label :lesson_type %><br/>
     <%= lesson.text_field :lesson_type, :readonly=>true%><br/>
     <%= lesson.label :name %><br/>
     <%= lesson.text_field :name %><br/>
```

I have tried out the following but it did not worked.

```
<div id = "<%= :lesson_type%>">
```

Would appreciate it if someone could help me out thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry..

```
#controller

def index
  ...
  lecture.lesson_type = @lesson_dom_id = "lecture" # line 5
  ...
end

#view
<div id="<%= @lesson_dom_id %>">
```